# How to send a file to a particular number in whatsapp using any plugin in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, share, url-launcher

I have gone through some answers there , but everywhere I was getting only how to send a text message to a particular mobile number from a flutter app . I need a way to send a file in whatsapp to a particular number in flutter . Any suggestions are welcome .

Here I am using url launcher , but file sharing is not being done .. Please help someone.

```
class UrlLauncherService {
  void launchWhatsApp({
    @required String phone,
    @required String message,
  }) async {
    String url() {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        return "whatsapp://wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
      } else {
        return "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone&text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
      }
    }

    if (await canLaunch(url())) {
      await launch(url());
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch ${url()}';
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'esys-flutter-share' plugin. Although there is some problems with the oficial versions, but you can use some PR from their git.
https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share

An example would be:

```
    await Share.file(
       'QR Code', 'qrcode.png', base64Decode(qrCode.image), 'image/png',
       text: qrCode.text);
```

You can use this with a button action, which will open up some options for sharing the file, where is Whatsapp as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering , here I am able to share the file in whatsapp or other media, but by providing mobile number I am not being able to send a file to that particular mobile number directly without choosing from my contacts in whatsapp.

Comment: In that case you should take a look at this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_social_content_share

Answer (score 0):

I think WhatsApp does not have any API for file sharing to a specific contact number. Because of this there is no flutter plugin yet. I use `Share.shareFiles([file_path]);` from [Flutter Share Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share) as a work around.